# How to blur the input field by default and toggle it after clicking on checkbox in angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, blur

```html
    <input (click)="check()" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">

    <input [(ngModel)]="second_month" value="2019-09" type="month">
```

I want second `input(type=month)` field to be blurred by default and if someone checks the checkbox, it will on blur the input field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean disabled/ locked by blur, then try this:

.ts

```
is_second_month_disabled = true;
```

.html

```
<input (click)="is_second_month_disabled = false" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">

<input [(ngModel)]="second_month" value="2019-09" type="month" [disabled]="is_second_month_disabled">
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-akevce?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: it works fine but it doesn't exactly looking disabled it's just yellowish

Comment: You can change the disabled color, design using css

Comment: how exactly I can do that?

Comment: input:disabled{background-color:red;}

Comment: do you know how to blur the text like I have this code - <input (click)="clickbox()" type="checkbox">
<span> Hey there
  <input [disabled]="ischecked" type="month">
</span>

Comment: I want to blur the text - "Hey there" too